# alignment and clickable area in ul based navigation

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am working on a simple UL based horizontal navigation. What I would like is for the clickable area to match the height and width of each LI. I have tried a lot of variations on this theme, but this is about the happiest compromise shown below, where I get about half the area within each LI to be clickable when the text is aligned in the middle. Thanks for any input.

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffaa00;
}
#main {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 890px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#nav {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 50px;
  width: 190px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
li:hover {
  background-color: #999;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 25px;
  width: 190px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#a">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#b">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#c">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#d">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#e">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#f">Link</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change `height` to `100%` and use [:before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) to [vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) text middle.

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffaa00;
}
#main {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 890px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#nav {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 50px;
  width: 190px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
li:hover {
  background-color: #999;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 190px;
}
a:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#a">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#b">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#c">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#d">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#e">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#f">Link</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```